# Loading layout xml failed

Tags: android, xml

I think I should present the whole layout structure so that you can figure out where is the problem. I am new to Android programming and am not sure what I am doing is right. I have main.xml loaded with listview. Then I have a menu and when pressing the menu, I load add.xml to add a new list to the listview. It is as follows and is working fine.

```
final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add, null);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("New Tracker").setView(addView)
            .setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    addWord((TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.IDeditText));
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
```

*add.xml* has an EditText view. When the user taps on the EditText, I would like to load another XML layout called description.xml. That is done as follows -

```
private void add() {
    final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add, null);

    EditText DescEditTxt = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionEdit);
    if(DescEditTxt != null)
    {
        DescEditTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                final View descriptionView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.description, null);
                setContentView(descriptionView);        

            }
       });
    }


    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("New Tracker").setView(addView)
            .setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    addWord((TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.IDeditText));
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
}
```

When the user has a focus on the EditText view, I tried to load the *description.xml* but The program crashed at `setContentView(descriptionView);`

My queries are

- Does that make sense with what I am doing? And is there any better approach for this?
- What could be the problem due to which the program crashed?

LOGCAT

```
03-17 06:15:24.918: E/InputEventReceiver(2093): Exception dispatching input event.
03-17 06:15:24.928: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:292)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:279)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at sg.SanThit.TrackMe.MainActivity$1.onFocusChange(MainActivity.java:117)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:4587)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:7325)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4375)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:6660)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6639)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6606)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6585)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:8184)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7377)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:740)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-17 06:15:25.048: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2093):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 06:15:25.048: D/AndroidRuntime(2093): Shutting down VM
03-17 06:15:25.062: W/dalvikvm(2093): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:292)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:279)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at sg.SanThit.TrackMe.MainActivity$1.onFocusChange(MainActivity.java:117)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:4587)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:7325)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4375)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:6660)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6639)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6606)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6585)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:8184)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7377)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:740)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-17 06:15:25.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2093):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 06:20:25.548: I/Process(2093): Sending signal. PID: 2093 SIG: 9
```

Comment: a lot of error in the error log. How to copy here?

Comment: There's a save button in the logcat tab. Select all lines and save to a log file then just copy and paste that in code brackets in your OP. You can also filter in logcat by type and other things. If you look at it and find the first line that references your project it should tell you the line number and above that, the source of error like `Caused by Null Pointer Exception` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

> (1)Does that make sense with what I am doing?Is there any better approach for this?

Part of your problem, in my opinion, is that you are inflating and trying to use too many `Layouts`. Inflating `Views` is ok but it seems like you are trying to use too many (3 so far that I can see). It would be much simpler and cleaner if you called `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()` then maybe `inflate` a `View` for your list if you need. If you want all of this to be in one `Activity` and are using API 11 or greater then you may want to consider using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Its hard to picture exactly what you have but if each `layout` doesn't have a lot of `Views` inside them, it may be easier just to put them in one `layout` and set `visibility` to `gone` until you need that `view` then change it to `visible`

```
What could be the problem due to which the program crashed?
```

**Edit**

The error is because you have a `ListActivity` but you don't have a `ListView` in your xml with a proper id. You need to have something like

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
.../>
```

If you only extend `Activity` and create your own `listview` then you don't need this. But if you extend `ListActivity` then you need this `ListView` in your xml. The following line in your logcat is how you can know this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Comment: Edited my answer. That should fix your problem

Comment: @Bryanyan did this fix your problem? If so, please accept so others can find it easily. If not, let me know what the problem is now and we can fix it